# Is there a router with configurable public IP address?

Tags: router, ip-address

Can you please point me to some routers on which I can manually set a public IP address?

This is not over ATM, the bridge to the external network is in my LAN (and I take the public IP Adresses directly from it), but I can't modify the internal settings because the owner won't let me.

Comment: The public IP is set by your ISP, so this will not be possible, unless you get a dedicated IP.

Comment: I do have one dedicated IP, but it is assigned thorugh the bridge. Anyway it isn't actually public, it's part of a bigger 10.x.x.x network.

Comment: I've never seen a router that would not let you configure IP addresses on it's interfaces.  That being said... you cannot simply use any arbitrary public ip address and expect it to work.  Basic networking principles won't let that work.  You must use an un-used IP address within the subnet your provider has assigned to you.  You might want to consider VPN'ing your traffic through that device, and then your provider will have no say to what traffic crosses between the two networks.

Comment: I do have a 3 "public" ip adresses for like 10 host. I just want to assign one of this IP to some kind of router (that I don't know :/ ) so that it will napt it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all home gateway products allow you to manually configure a static public IP address on the Ethernet WAN port.

Every router I've ever come across lets you do this.